# Reference for a lemma on acyclic subgraph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Lemma. Let $D$ be a digraph. Then there exists an acyclic subdigraph $D'$ of $D$ such that the total degree (i.e. out-degree plus in-degree) of $v$ in $D'$ is at least the out-degree of $v$ in $D$ for every vertex $v \in V(D)$.

I notice that I need the above lemma. The lemma is correct, looks fundamental and the proof is pretty easy. Hence I believe that it is known somewhere. Could anyone point out the reference for it? I will be much indebted.